# Google Sheet Script Editor - Multiple Sumifs in report format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I`m trying to do the following task.

The test version is listed below

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K1UFjUn4o_ciB6ZUo8E23G0E-S7tKTssr6bXRAlOSo8/edit?usp=sharing

I`m trying to fill in those yellow highlighted rows in "Atlantic", "Central", "Western", "Eastern" tabs which come from "RAW" tab.

Basically, there are tabs for each zone and then tables for each vendor in each tab by months

How would I do this in google app script?

Comment: @ra89fi, please let me know if this is too much of an ask... it is basically similar logic as the previous question, but in a bigger format and fixed format given that there are given tables already in each tab + also there is another attribute called Zones now

Comment: So I have to calculate for each zones, for each vendor, for given months, convs. as specified ?

Comment: oh yes, so conversion A is sum (Conversion A1 + Conversion A2) and conversion B is sum (Conversion B1 + Conversion B2) and conversion C is sum(Conversion C1 + Conversion C2) and conversion D is sum(Conversion D1 + Conversion D2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Delete `conversion notes` rows from `RAW` sheet first.

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawSheet = ss.getSheetByName('RAW');
  var rawValues = rawSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  rawValues.shift();

  // will be months present in data
  // { 0: true, 1: true ... }
  var mos = {};
  // well be vendors present in data
  // { Google: true ... }
  var vens = {};

  // data structure
  var ds = {};

  rawValues.forEach(function(row) {
    // check below cols
    var month = Math.floor(new Date(row[2]).getMonth());
    var zone = row[12];
    var ven = row[13];

    mos[month] = true; // set month on mos
    vens[ven] = true; // set vendor on vens

    ds[zone] = ds[zone] || {}; // zone
    ds[zone][ven] = ds[zone][ven] || {}; // vendor

    // set conversion value
    if (!ds[zone][ven][month]) {
      ds[zone][ven][month] = [
        // A
        parseInt(row[4]) + parseInt(row[5]),
        // B
        parseInt(row[6]) + parseInt(row[7]),
        // C
        parseInt(row[8]) + parseInt(row[9]),
        // D
        parseInt(row[10]) + parseInt(row[11])
      ];
    } else {
      ds[zone][ven][month] = [
        // A
        ds[zone][ven][month][0] + parseInt(row[4]) + parseInt(row[5]),
        // B
        ds[zone][ven][month][1] + parseInt(row[6]) + parseInt(row[7]),
        // C
        ds[zone][ven][month][2] + parseInt(row[8]) + parseInt(row[9]),
        // D
        ds[zone][ven][month][3] + parseInt(row[10]) + parseInt(row[11])
      ];
    }
  });

  Logger.log(vens);
  // put empty vendor for a zone if not exists
  Object.keys(ds).forEach(function(z) {
    ds[z] = ds[z] || {};
    Object.keys(vens).forEach(function(v) {
      ds[z][v] = ds[z][v] || {};
    });
  });
  // Logger.log(ds);

  var months = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'];
  // filter months to get months present in sheet data in order
  months = months.filter(function(m) {
    return mos[m] == true;
  });
  // Logger.log(months);

  // Z : { V: [ row, row... ]... }
  var rs = {};
  Object.keys(ds).forEach(function(z) {
    rs[z] = rs[z] || {};

    Object.keys(ds[z]).forEach(function(v) {
      rs[z][v] = rs[z][v] || [];

      months.forEach(function(m) {
        if (ds[z][v][m]) {
          rs[z][v].push(ds[z][v][m]);
        } else {
          rs[z][v].push(['N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  // Logger.log(rs);

  // start of vendors in all sheets, [row, col]
  // must be same in all zone sheets, which is now
  var pos = {
    Google: [3, 7],
    Nielsen: [21, 7],
    IBM: [39, 7],
    Samsung: [57, 7]
  };

  // write rows
  Object.keys(rs).forEach(function(z) {
    try {
      ss.insertSheet(z);
    } catch (e) {}

    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(z);
    Object.keys(rs[z]).forEach(function(v) {
      sh.getRange(pos[v][0], pos[v][1], rs[z][v].length, 4).setValues(rs[z][v]);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: OMG.... you are just amazing, This is working perfectly... I am now in the middle of my meeting at work, let me revi:)ew this codes and will follow up with questions!!!!! :)

Comment: You formatted the sheets perfectly, which made my job a lot easier.

Comment: Your codes as well :) - the only thing is it is counting only one row for month, so, if data has multiple 1/1/2019, then it is counting only the first occurrence. Is it possible to sum all 1/1/2019 occurrences for relevant vendor and zone?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Let me check.

Comment: shoot, its my bad, I should have gave an clear example of this, realized that months in the current raw data is all unique..

Comment: it did occur to me before then looked at sheet, yes, then coded that way, try now!

Comment: Jeeez, working perfectly... again, Thanks Magician !:) I wish there was double thumbs up functionalities in Stackoverflow...

Comment: For that statement if (!ds[zone][ven][month]), would it be right to interpret it as "when Zone and Vendor and Month combination do not match? - so if one of the elements do not exist as combination, then compute the sum values?

Comment: the ! condition is, if month doesn't exist for a Zone,Vendor combo create it with new values. else add to previous values.